# How to find how far to rotate with position?

Tags: math, rotation

Let's say I had my player at position 1, and my enemy at position 2. What would I need to do with  the two points's positions to get the rotation needed for the player to look at the enemy, assuming that the player starts at zero degrees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x1 = player's X coordinate
y1 = player's Y coordinate

x2 = enemy's X coordinate
y2 = enemy's Y coordinate

angle = math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / math.pi()
```

from there, you can get the angle you needed to turn : )